# How to iterate over files in URL with bash?

Tags: file, loops, url

I know how to iterate through a directory with bash. Howered, what if it's a remote directory?

URL would be :
http://jenkinsmediaprocessor:XXXX/job/C/280/artifact/Test/bin/x86/Debug/